# Simple question on discrete uniform distribution

Tags: conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

We have a random variable $X$ uniformly distributed on the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Assume $s<<n$.
Can anyone please advise, how to find the conditional probability $P\{X = k | X\le s \}$, where $k\in\{1,\ldots,s\}$?

More specifically, let us construct a random variable $Y$ in the following way. We generate a random number $X$ uniformly distributed on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and if $X\le s$, we assign $Y:=X$. Otherwise we discard $X$ and generate again. Is it true, that $Y$ will follow uniform distribution on $\{1,\ldots,s\}$?

Comment: Yes!  Why not?  n items and a subset of s members - none special.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it would.

As a side note you should be a little careful because you're double using X and Y for your random variable and for the value the random variable takes on. You should use lower case for the latter.